# Hardware accelerated decoding with FFmpeg falls back to software decoding

Tags: java, ffmpeg

So I have followed the FFmpeg example for hardware accelerated decoding exactly as it is (I am referring to this example).

```cpp
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c#L76
```

But I still seem to be decoding with the software decoder. When I open the task manager on windows the GPU isn't getting used. Before I make a call to *av_hwframe_transfer_data()* I check whether the frame is in the relevant *hw_pix_fmt* format and it is. Everything works, no errors, nothing, except the GPU is doing nothing. Now as an example I tried decoding a video that uses vp9 as a codec. If I specify the hardware accelerated codec I want by name it actually does work.

```cpp
vidCodec=avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("vp9_cuvid");
```

When I do this and look at the task manager I can see that the CPU does much less work and my GPU actually does Video Decode work. Having to specify the hardware accelerated decoder for every single video I am decoding is ridiculous though.

Edit: as per user4581301's answer, here are the pieces of relevant code. (It's actually in java because I am using the java FFmpeg wrapper but it's basically just making a bunch of calls to FFmpeg functions.)

```java
 ArrayList<String> deviceTypes = new ArrayList<>();
 int type = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE;
                    while ((type = av_hwdevice_iterate_types(type)) != AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE) {
                        BytePointer p = av_hwdevice_get_type_name(type);

                        deviceTypes.add(CString(p));
                    }
                    boolean flag=false;

                    for(int j=0;j<deviceTypes.size();j++){
                        type = av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name(deviceTypes.get(j));
                       
                        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
                            final AVCodecHWConfig config = avcodec_get_hw_config(vidCodec, i);
                            if (config == null) {
                                break;

                            }
                            if ((config.methods() & AV_CODEC_HW_CONFIG_METHOD_HW_DEVICE_CTX)!=0 &&
                                    config.device_type() == type) {

                                hw_pix_fmt = config.pix_fmt();
                                flag=true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(flag){
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    if(hw_pix_fmt ==AV_PIX_FMT_NONE){
                        System.err.println("Decoder " + vidCodec.name() + " does not support device types: " );
                        for(int i=0;i<deviceTypes.size();i++){
                            System.out.print(deviceTypes.get(i)+ " " );
                        }

                    }
                   /* Allocate a codec context for the decoder */
                if ((video_c = avcodec_alloc_context3(vidCodec)) == null) {
                    throw new Exception("avcodec_alloc_context3() error: Could not allocate video decoding context.");
                }


                /* copy the stream parameters from the muxer */

                if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(video_c, video_st.codecpar())) < 0) {
                    releaseUnsafe();
                    throw new Exception("avcodec_parameters_to_context() error " + ret + ": Could not copy the video stream parameters.");
                }
              

                    video_c.get_format(AvFormatGetter.getInstance());
                    AVBufferRef hardwareDeviceContext =av_hwdevice_ctx_alloc(type);

                    if ((ret = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(hardwareDeviceContext, type,(String) null, null, 0)) < 0) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to create specified HW device. error " + ret);

                    }else{
                        video_c.hw_device_ctx(av_buffer_ref(hardwareDeviceContext));

                    }
    


                
//The function that gets called for get_format
@Override
 public int call(AVCodecContext context, IntPointer format) {
            int p;


            for (int i=0;;i++) {
                if ((p=format.get(i)) == hw_pix_fmt) {
                    return p;
                }
                if(p==-1){
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(hw_pix_fmt +" is not found in the codec context");
            // Error

            return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
        }
    
//The method that's used for decoding video frames
  public Optional<Boolean> decodeVideoFrame(AVPacket pkt, boolean readPacket, boolean keyFrames) throws Exception {

        int ret;
        // Decode video frame
        if (readPacket) {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(video_c, pkt);
          
            if (ret < 0) {
                System.out.println("error during decoding");
                return Optional.empty();
            }

            if (pkt.data() == null && pkt.size() == 0) {
                pkt.stream_index(-1);
            }
           
        }

        // Did we get a video frame?
        while (true) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_c, picture_hw);

            if (ret == AVERROR_EAGAIN() || ret == AVERROR_EOF()) {
                if (pkt.data() == null && pkt.size() == 0) {
                    return Optional.empty();
                } else {

                    return Optional.of(true);

                }
            } else if (ret < 0) {

                // Ignore errors to emulate the behavior of the old API
                // throw new Exception("avcodec_receive_frame() error " + ret + ": Error during video decoding.");
                return Optional.of(true);

            }

            if (!keyFrames || picture.pict_type() == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I) {
              
                if(picture_hw.format()==hw_pix_fmt){
                    if (av_hwframe_transfer_data(
                            picture, // The frame that will contain the usable data.
                            picture_hw, // Frame returned by avcodec_receive_frame()
                            0) < 0) {
                        throw new Exception("Could not transfer data from gpu to cpu. ");

                    }
                }
               //... The rest of the method here
                return Optional.of(false);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always show the code. Even when you're following a tutorial to the letter. All too often the problem turns out to be a small transcription error.

Comment: Side note: Don't write "doesn't work". It contains no information. Even in the title it's better to state what happened instead so that someone who finds the question in a search results list knows you still got software decoding but the program didn't crash like theirs does.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the advice. Initially I wanted to avoid a code sample because I didn't know if it was gonna be a bit incoherent because I am using java but I suppose it's probably better to have it.

Comment: Translating code from one language to another, if that is in fact what you're doing here, is fraught with peril You have to understand BOTH languages to a pretty high level to capture all the nuances in the behaviour of the source language and then reproduce the behaviour exactly in the new language. If you do a line-to-line direct translation you tend to get a poor result at best, and more likely you get [All Your Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) style gibberish. My Java's about 20 years stale so I'd be more a hinderance than a help here.

Comment: @user4581301 I am not translating code, the program is written in java and makes native calls to c++ libraries. Perhaps I should try to make a c++ version and see how that one works though.. I'm probably more likely to get help that way as well.